# Checkbox UI not changing when trigger using Redux Persist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks, redux-persist

I'm trying to persist the state of multiple checkboxes in a FlatList, I successfully can change states of *isSelected* but it Checkbox UI won't render until I only refresh the app.

So here's my initial state in **dayReducer.js**.

```
const initialDayState = {
  dayState: [
    { isDaySelected: false, key: 'Sunday' },
    { isDaySelected: false, key: 'Monday' },
    { isDaySelected: false, key: 'Tuesday' },
    { isDaySelected: false, key: 'Wednesday' },
    { isDaySelected: false, key: 'Thursday' },
    { isDaySelected: false, key: 'Friday' },
    { isDaySelected: false, key: 'Saturday' },
  ],
}

export const daysReducer = (state = initialDayState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case ActionTypes.SET_DAYS:
      return [...payload]

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Also here in my **index.js** my redux selected

```
const selectedDayState = useSelector((state) => state.daysReducer.dayState)
```

And my FlatList with Checkbox

```
<FlatList 
...
data={selectedDayState}
...
  <CheckBox
  ...
    value={item?.isDaySelected}
    onChange={() => handleMultipleSelectedDay(index)}
  />
/>
```

And Finally, the Handle Multiple Selected Day Function which I also dispatch the new State of the selected days.

```
const handleMultipleSelectedDay = (index) => {
    const days = [...selectedDayState]
    days[index].isDaySelected = !days[index].isDaySelected
    dispatch(setDays(days))
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your reducer function:

```
export const daysReducer = (state = initialDayState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case ActionTypes.SET_DAYS:
      return {...state, dayState: payload }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

The way you are updating the state is incorrect.

Note: Also, look at `immer js`, `redux-toolkit` they really help in managing nested objects and also decreases development time.

Comment: thank you for this, but the UI of the checkbox isn't updating even the state changes. It only updates when I refresh the screen/app.

Comment: so I tried making another useState const [day, setDay] = useState(selectedDayState) and use this in handling function instead const days = [...day]. it works now.